# Not able to connect to CentOS VM from Mac - (Setting up Jenkins pipeline)

Tags: jenkins, centos, macos-mojave, netcat

I am following a course to setup Jenkins pipeline in a Linux VM.
My host machine is MacOS-mojave.

- 1) I started the CentOs VM via VirtualBox.
- 2) I SSH ed to the VM via Terminal in Mac with root user.
- 3) I installed Jenkins in VM. All successful.
- 4) I checked in a browser in the VM and Jenkins is running in port 8080.
- 5) I added the VM host name 'osboxes 'to Mac hosts file.
- 6) I cleared the DNS cache using sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
- 7) Went to the browser and hit osboxes:8080. Safari saying not able to connect.
- 8) I did nc -vz 192.168.1.13 8080..it says connection refused
- 9) I did ping 192.168.1.3 from Mac terminal and it is giving me data.

What is the problem here. Please help

Comment: Could you please let me know - what set-ups you did you have to do to be able to ssh into it?  I have posted [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/1026743/how-to-ssh-into-centos-7-8-virtualbox-vm-from-macos)   question on ServerFault site.  Hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

In the Virtual Box configure a host only network and assign it to the Jenkins VM. I haven't tried that approach using hostname, but what I do is put a static IP to the VM so I always know it's IP... Then I can put a record on the hosts file.

I am assuming that you are using NAT networking on the VM.